# How to... simple enumlike type in codefirst?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I have following issue:
My User Class contains a rank field. How to define Rank so it will behave like enum type but on database, using code first :S (dont rly know how to say this).

This is my user class:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [EmailAddress]
    [MaxLength(254)]
    public String Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public String Password { get; set; }

    public String Salt { get; set; }

    //[DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
    public String Avatar { get; set; }

    public bool Banned { get; set; }

    public Rank Rank { get; set; }

    public String Information { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my first try:

```
public class Rank
{
    [Key]
    public int RankId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

it works, when I add:

```
[ForeignKey("RankId")]
public Rank Rank { get; set; }
public int RankId { get; set; }
```

But I've been told that using int RnakId there, is a waste and field Name is enough... I want my rank to contain strings with their rank -.- like: admin, user, mod. So i can later pick some of already defined ranks instead of typing it evry time.
Do you know any other method of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could parse it back and forth between an enum in code, but that would require a code edit and recompile to add new ranks.

You can not get rid of the id field as it is needed for the foreign key.
The id is useful when storing in a combobox on the ui.

Comment: Whats when I make `public String Name { get; set; }` a `[Key]`?

Comment: Then there is no need for a separate table

Comment: Without knowing the context. Then i think the solution you already have is the best one. 
Sometimes when i need the "enum" feature i would create another field in Rank named "SYSTEM_KEY" where i would store some string to use for comparing against inside the application.
This way you have the flexibility to rename a rank and add new ones without changing the application. Of course if you need new behavior you need to change the application and look for another "SYSTEM_KEY"